# Another driver pulled me over on the motorway and asked for petrol. Was it a scam attempt?

Tags: driving, czech-republic, scams

These days, I was driving on the D11 in Czechia in the early evening hours. Shortly before Prague, I had stopped at a service area. Not too long after I had pulled out and was back on the motorway, I noticed the car behind me flashing its headlights at me and gesturing at me to pull over. The car had UK plates; I was driving my own car, also with foreign plates. Both cars are medium-sized passenger cars, European premium brands, around 10 years old.

I remembered hearing about similar scams in other parts of the world, where people will stop passing cars, claiming there is something wrong with the car or, alternatively, that they need help, and then rob the driver or steal the car.

With this in mind, I pulled over and opened a window but left the transmission in drive and the engine running. The driver of the other car got out, showed me a business card, asked if I spoke English and then explained in accented English (he claimed to be Arab) that he was having “petrol problems” with his car and was traveling with his wife and baby, and asked if I could help him.

At that point I decided the whole thing was getting too fishy and I drove off.

What raised my suspicion was:

- He claimed “petrol problems” (running out of fuel?) although we had just passed a gas station less than 2 km before. I would imagine that it would have been much easier for him to stop there and ask for help.
- In the unlikely event that something were to have happened on the short stretch of road after the service area, there are still emergency phones along the highway, which he could have used.
- Why would he flag down a car with foreign plates instead of a local one, whose driver would be more likely able to help him (e.g. speaking the local language, knowing where to get help)? Whereas I would expect scammers to be more likely to target foreigners (more valuables in the car, less savvy driver).

How likely is it that this was a scam attempt? Does this resemble any well-known scams—and if so, are they known to have occurred around Prague before? Or is there any good reason why this behavior could be legitimate and innocuous?

Comment: I don't see how this is answerable. We know nothing about the individual who flagged you down. We can talk about likelihood and frequency of such scams, but they will tell you nothing about your individual case.

Comment: @DJClayworth A possible answer might include if such scams are known to have happened around Prague, or if there are other reasons this should have raised a red flag—or a good reason why this behavior could be legitimate and innocuous. I’m specifically not asking “was this guy a scammer” but I’d like to know how likely it is that he was.

Comment: I believe the emergency phones are for actual emergencies (mostly car crashes), not when you just have problems with your car.

Comment: "Why would he flag down a car with foreign plates instead of a local one" Maybe because there's a better chance the driver would speak English? Not every Czech driver does.

Comment: @svick Before cell phones became widespread, emergency phones were the only way to get road assistance, as in the case of a broken-down car. From my personal experience I can recall three instances in which we used an emergency telephone for that purpose.

Comment: You're lucky you didn't get robbed. Next time avoid stopping and press on the gas.

Comment: @JonathanReez That’s why I kept the engine running, transmission in drive, and watched very closely who was getting out of the other car. After reading through the links in the answer, I realize the advice is not to even slow down.

Comment: Never stop on highway! It's strictly forbidden and dangerous, unless the police orders you to stop. If someone has a breakdown, he should wait for specialized highway service.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo The shoulder is for emergency situations: mostly technical issues with the car (not all of which immobilize the car immediately), or accidents (if the cars involved can still move). Another occasionally cited example is if someone in the car is about to throw up. Of course, if the police instructs you to stop, that overrides everything else. In this case, it could well have been an issue with my own car that I might not have noticed.

Comment: @user149408 OK it was an oversimplication, you need to stop there. If you see someone who need medical assistance, you are oblidged to stop and provide any help you are able to. But neither was the case in the question.

Comment: @GayotFow I’ve edited the question to be more answerable.

Comment: @svick A breakdown, including running out of fuel, is clearly an emergency situation. What else could you do but phone for help? You're not allowed to walk along the highway, for example. So do you expect people to try to flag down passing motorists (who, by the way, aren't allowed to stop)? Or to wait in their cars until they're in immediate danger of dying of starvation before they can call it an emergency and use the phone?

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question is very answerable. Although we can't know if this specific incident was a scam (maybe the guy really was running out of fuel), the answer that this is a known scam is useful to other people who might be in a similar situation (or, rather, might learn from it to avoid that situation). The whole point of Stack Exchange questions is that they should be useful to others.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo — I know that stopping on the highway is illegal in USA (but not enforced!).  I don't know whether it's true in Czechia or any other country.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your experience is typical of a well-known scam

- [Police warning over motorway scam in which well-dressed drivers pretend to run out of fuel and ask for cash in return for worthless gold rings](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2990201/Police-warning-motorway-scam-dressed-drivers-pretend-run-fuel-ask-cash-return-worthless-gold-rings.html)
- [Fraudsters are attempting to con motorway drivers out of money by flagging them down and claiming they have run out of petrol.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-leeds-30387026)
- [Petrol scam on French roads ... he said his wife and small baby were in the car](http://www.survivefrance.com/t/petrol-scam-on-french-roads/4812)
- [In the 90ies people tried to scam tourists and travellers on the highways of many European countries by making them stop, telling a beautiful and poor story and making them to pay money for gas, food etc.](https://www.off-the-path.com/en/the-highway-scammer/)